# Can I add a row to a matrix based on specific rows in the matrix rather than all?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a matrix in a report that returns five rows. effectively this

r1 | s11 | s12 | s13 | s14

..

r5 | s51 | s52 | s53 | s54

I need to add a sixth row that computes a value based on the values in row 1 and row 5.

r6 | s11+s51 | s12 + s52 | etc....

Is this possible and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: I don't know any way to do it in the matrix itself, but it should be relatively straightforward to do it in the SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Mark said, to do it in a query is pretty simple.

Alternatively, you could add another row to your matrix, and use an expression to add the values of the first and last value in each column:

```
=First(Fields!s.Value) + Last(Fields!s.Value)
```

Comment: I'm accepting the point to do it in SQL rather than the expression, which doesn't seem to work for me in SSRS2005